# Table caption and Table Numbering

Tags: tables, apa-style

I try to change the numbering and formatting of my table(s). Currently I am working with this

```
\documentclass[twoside, titlepage=firstiscover, open=right, 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize, labelfont = bf]{caption}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
 \begin{table}[!h]
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{footnotesize}
    \caption{My Table Title\\}
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}lYYYYY@{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{bla}\\
    \cmidrule{2-6}
    this & is  & some & really  & random & text  \\
    \midrule
    bla & 0 & 1 & 2 & \textbf{3} & 4\\
    blubb & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\
    bla blubb & 10 & \textbf{11} & 12 & \textbf{13} & \textbf{14}\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
          \footnotesize
          \item \textit{Note.} This is a note!
    \end{tablenotes}
    \label{some label}
    \end{footnotesize}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

With this code I get a table caption of this form:

> **Table 1.1.:** My table title.

I would rather - in accordance with APA7 - like to have this form:

> **Table 1.1**
>
> *This is my table title.*

How can I change my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This caption style can be relative easy implemented in the `talltblr` table, which is `tabularray` package  way to write `threeparttable`s:

```
\documentclass[twoside,
               titlepage=firstiscover,
               open=right, 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, counter}
\usepackage[skip=0ex, width=\linewidth,
            format=plain,
            font = {small, sf},
            labelfont = bf, labelsep = newline,
            singlelinecheck = off]{caption}
\NewTblrTheme{captionof}% needed that talltblr instead of own caption settings
                        % consider settings of the caption package 
{%
    \DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}%
    {\addtocounter{table}{-1}%
     \captionof{table}{\InsertTblrText{caption}}%
    }
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!h]
    \begin{talltblr}[
  theme = captionof,            % <--- for considering caption package setup
caption = {My Table Title},
  label = {tab:???},
remark{Note:} = This is a note! % <--- "table notes"
                    ]{colspec = {@{}l *{4}{X[c]} @{}} }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c}
    &   \SetCell[c=5]{c}   bla
        &   &   &   &           \\
    \midrule
this & is & some & really & random & text \\
    \midrule
bla & 0 & 1 & 2 & \textbf{3} & 4\\
blubb & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\
bla blubb & 10 & \textbf{11} & 12 & \textbf{13} & \textbf{14}\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
From February 2024 is available new package `tblr-extras` which enables simple writing captions in `longtblr` and `talltblr` tables using `caption` package.

My first test of it shows, that it works fine and make writing of captions in the `longtblr` and `talltblr` tables much simpler by use of `caption` syntax.

Manuel E. Merino, thank you very much for this nice package!

Using it, above solution now can be:

```
\documentclass[twoside,
               titlepage=firstiscover,
               open=right, 11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage[skip=0ex, belowskip=0.5ex,
            format=plain,
            font = {small, sf},
            labelfont = bf, labelsep = newline,
            singlelinecheck = off]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tblr-extras}        % new package   
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, 
                caption}        % new library

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {My Table Title},
  label = {tab:???},
remark{Note} = This is a note! % <--- "table notes"
                    ]{colspec = {@{}l *{5}{X[c]} @{}} }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c}
    &   \SetCell[c=5]{c}   bla
        &   &   &   &           \\
    \midrule
this & is & some & really & random & text \\
    \midrule
bla & 0 & 1 & 2 & \textbf{3} & 4\\
blubb & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\
bla blubb & 10 & \textbf{11} & 12 & \textbf{13} & \textbf{14}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}    
\end{document}
```

Compilation result is:

[image]

Comment: you can also use `caption` captions and `tabularray` with `tblr-extras` and `\UseTblrLibrary{caption}`. It should apply caption style to all tall and long tblrs

Comment: @Mane32, I observe this new package but not tested it yet. Recently I'm to busy with some other obligation and unfortunately haven't spare time for testing it :-(. Anyway, thank you very much for remain me on it :-).

Comment: @Mane32, your package is super! Thank you very much for it.

Comment: +1: Great showcase of the new package

Answer (score 0):

This is easy with the `caption` package:

```
    \documentclass[twoside, titlepage=firstiscover, open=right, 11pt]{scrbook}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{mathpazo}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{threeparttablex}
    \usepackage[font=footnotesize, labelfont = bf]{caption}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \usepackage{threeparttable}
    \usepackage{caption}

    \begin{document}

     \begin{table}[!h]
        \begin{threeparttable}
    \captionsetup{belowskip=2ex, labelsep = newline}
        \begin{footnotesize}
        \caption{My Table Title\\}
        \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}lYYYYY@{}}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{bla}\\
        \cmidrule{2-6}
        this & is & some & really & random & text \\
        \midrule
        bla & 0 & 1 & 2 & \textbf{3} & 4\\
        blubb & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\
        bla blubb & 10 & \textbf{11} & 12 & \textbf{13} & \textbf{14}\\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
        \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
              \footnotesize
              \item \textit{Note.} This is a note!
        \end{tablenotes}
        \label{some label}
        \end{footnotesize}
        \end{threeparttable}
        \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but surprisingly that does not work. It is still all in one line. "belowskip=2ex" has an effect but "labelsep=newline" does not. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Not really, since  I loaded your code and only added the caption package loading.  Did you load caption as the last package, as I did in my code?

Comment: Yes, I did. This is really strange ... 
Thank you anyway! Maybe one more question: I do not want Table Number and Table Title to be centered. How can I change this?

Comment: Never mind. Now it works. There was a problem with my label. Still, there is my open question about the centering. Any ideas?

Comment: @offline: I tried various possibilities with caption, such as `justification=raggedright` or `singlelinecheck=false`, but they didn't work. Maybe this is due to the threeparttable environment?